# Как добавлять метки и почему нельзя задать вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Где-то видел, что на SOen меток в 5 раз больше, а у нас даже нету метки [com-port](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/com-port). Это в каких-то голосованиях обсуждается или как?

Второй вопрос родился при вводе первого: как добавлять метки? Что за хитрый мозг следит за правильностью вопроса на мете?

Comment: Эвристика проверки качества вопроса закрыта во избежание злоупотреблений. Странная логика у человека который её писал, вместо мифического DDOSа некачественными вопросами он теперь постоянно получает реальную пачку вопросов вида: "Почему скрипт опять отклонил мой хороший вопрос?". Лучше бы вместо принудительного отказа этот оцениватель просто проставлял примерную оценку качества вопроса в виде числа, а у юзеров была бы возможность самим фильтровать все что ниже `n` баллов.

Comment: это на вопрос почему нельзя задать вопрос?

Answer (score 5):

1. Метка создаётся сама как только её кто-то приписал к вопросу. Кто-то с достаточной для этого репутацией [(а именно 150)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

   Подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges
2. Тут на эту тему уже штук 5 вопросов было, но никто ничего не меняет.